# Half-life Unit Notations

Tags: energy, nuclear-engineering, nuclear-technology, unit

I was looking for some element's half-life, on the following website:

http://nucleardata.nuclear.lu.se/toi/listnuc.asp?sql=&A1=214&A2=214&Z=88

For 214,88-Ra, the half-life is shown to be:    2.46 s 3

I am unsure what the "3" stands for, is it  "$\cdot 10^{-3}$"?

Thank you for your help and time guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The half life of Radium 214 is 2.46[s]. You can check half times at the following [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_radioactive_nuclides_by_half-life).

I am not sure what the 3 stands for, but I suspect that this is some sort of annotation/footnote that was not properly inserted in the webpage.